# WordPress hiding categories view from edit posts

Tags: wordpress

I have created a edit link on my wordpress where subscribers can edit their posts. When they click this it takes them back to the admin portal to edit post. I want to make sure they can't see the categories widget on the right side how do I remove that from a user seeing this?

```
<?php edit_post_link(__("Edit Post"), ''); ?>
```

I ahve this un the function.php file but need to know how to make it just for subscribers.

```
 function wpse60590_remove_metaboxes() { if() remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv' , 'post' , 'normal' ); remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag' , 'post' , 'normal' ); } add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpse60590_remove_metaboxes' );
```

Comment: duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/hide-tag-and-category-boxes-from-the-post-editor

Comment: Do you want to remove categories widget from page or post for subscribers users?

Comment: remove it from the edit post page for subscribers

Comment: on my site I allow users to create posts and edit them. But when they edit them I don't want them to be able to change the categories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the capabilities of these users' role to prevent them from working with categories. The capability you need to disable for their role should be "manage_categories".

Just make sure all of the users you wish to limit are in the same role (e.g. "Contributor" or something).

In my experience the easiest way to manage capabilities for roles is the [Members Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).

Once installed, go to Users -> Roles -> Select the role you wish to change. Find "manage_categories", uncheck it, and save.

If you are using a custom post type, we may have to add some settings where you register the taxonomy to specify the ability to assign a category to a post.

Comment: thanks Brian but I am using Masterplan to manage my user so this wont work. I need to code this. 

I found the following but no idea how to make this just for subscribers.

function wpse60590_remove_metaboxes() {
   if() remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 

}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpse60590_remove_metaboxes' );

Comment: Try this one for subscribe user only

global $current_user; // Use global
get_currentuserinfo(); // Make sure global is set, if not set it.
if ( ! user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" ) ) // Check user object has not got subscriber role
    echo 'User is a not Subscriber';
else
   function wpse60590_remove_metaboxes()
    {
      if() remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv' , 'post' , 'normal' );
   remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 
    } 
      add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpse60590_remove_metaboxes' );

Comment: @Chirag1162 , That's a good way to go about it, but we are not ENABLING something for users above subscriber, we are DISabling something for a specific role.

I would change `( ! user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" ) )`

to:

`( user_can( $current_user, "contributor" ) )`

Assuming that the contributor role is the one you want to disable it for. This function will now run IF the user is a contributor.